# Gremlin- find and connect sub-graphs

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, graph-databases

My graph contains an undirected topological network data and my goal is to build a query that finds all sub networks that apply to specific networking rules, create vertex for each subnetwork and connect those who have path between them. The intention is to minimize the big graph by replacing each subnetwork-subgraph in one vertex.
To find all subnetworks I took 'connected components' query from gremlin recopies
And added my networking rules to the stopping conditions. But right now I'm having hard time connecting this sub network to each other.

I'm providing here sample graph script (using different networking domain) that contains PC, Routers and other equipment nodes. Query should find all LANs by grouping connected PCs, and for each LAN return other LAN ids that have path to it.

Direction has no meaning in this graph, and path between subgraphs may contain many types of nodes (routers, equipment etc.).
My GraphDB is OrientDB.

[Networking Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/girDj.png)

Result should look like this:

```
==>LAN 1: {pcs: [1, 2, 3], connected LANs: [LAN 2, LAN 3]}  
==>LAN 2: {pcs: [4, 5, 6], connected LANs: [LAN 1]}  
==>LAN 3: {pcs: [8, 7], connected LANs: [LAN 1]}
```

This is query's first part (finding all sub networks):

```
g.V().hasLabel('PC').emit(cyclicPath().or().not(both())).
 repeat(__.where(without('a')).store('a').both()).until(or(cyclicPath(), hasLabel('Router'))).
 group().by(path().unfold().limit(1)).
 by(path().local(unfold().filter(hasLabel('PC')).values('id')).unfold().dedup().fold()).unfold()
```

**My questions are:**

1. I can identify connectivity between sub networks by traversing some arbitrary node from every sub network till I reach node that exist on other sub network. **How do I write it in gremlin**?
2. How can I create new graph out of this query results?
3. What is the performance of this type of query in a big graph, say 30M nodes?

Create graph script:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV("PC").property("id","1").as("pc1").
addV("PC").property("id","2").as("pc2").
addV("PC").property("id","3").as("pc3").
addV("PC").property("id","4").as("pc4").
addV("PC").property("id","5").as("pc5").
addV("PC").property("id","6").as("pc6").
addV("PC").property("id","7").as("pc7").
addV("PC").property("id","8").as("pc8").
addV("Router").property("id","9").as("router1").
addV("Router").property("id","10").as("router2").
addV("Equipment").property("id","11").as("eq1").
addV("Equipment").property("id","12").as("eq2").
addV("Equipment").property("id","13").as("eq3").
addV("Equipment").property("id","14").as("eq4").
addE("Line").from("pc1").to("pc2").
addE("Line").from("pc1").to("eq3").
addE("Line").from("pc2").to("pc3").
addE("Line").from("pc3").to("eq1").
addE("Line").from("pc3").to("eq3").
addE("Line").from("pc4").to("pc5").
addE("Line").from("pc4").to("pc6").
addE("Line").from("pc5").to("pc6").
addE("Line").from("pc7").to("pc8")
addE("Line").from("router1").to("pc7").
addE("Line").from("router1").to("pc8").
addE("Line").from("router1").to("eq2").
addE("Line").from("router2").to("eq4").
addE("Line").from("eq1").to("router1").
addE("Line").from("eq3").to("router2").
addE("Line").from("eq4").to("pc4").
iterate()
```

Comment: You can use this workspace to demonstrate your problem:  https://gremlify.com/tgpdyk6n3ro

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great answer because I think that I have to jump to your last question and ignore the first two of the three:

> What is the performance of this type of query in a big graph, say 30M nodes?

If you modified the "Connected Component" recipe found [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#connected-components) then I assume you read further down about the general expense of this sort of query for both OLTP and OLAP. I'd imagine that for 30M vertices you should be looking at OLAP-based processing (as opposed to that script you presented above). I suppose you might be able to do it with TinkerGraph/GraphComputer on a large enough machine with a lot of memory, but this might just be a job for `SparkGraphComputer` as suggested toward the [end of the recipe](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#_large_graphs).

I think that your first two questions seem to depend on your approach to and success around the third question and that those initial questions might get more focused or even change a bit once you get that far. Perhaps it would be best to try to get your OLAP approach to "connected components" settled and then come back with some more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do plan to try this in OLAP when I get to the big graph.
But is there a better approach to extract this sub-graphs than 'connected components' query? I'm new to gremlin and took one road, but maybe there is other gremlin api that better suits my goal.
I'm trying to get both parts -find sub-graphs & connect them- work in one gremlin query and avoid java code in the middle.
Thanks again

Comment: I feel like in most cases where there is a use case like yours that requires OLAP style processing over the entire graph, there is no one size fits all answer. If you haven't considered it already you might consider writing your own `VertexProgram` that will run inside a `GraphComputer`. Perhaps you could then capture all the logic you are looking for. https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graphcomputer

Comment: I also don't think you need to try to make everything happen with Gremlin for OLAP. I wouldn't go on a quest to write one Gremlin query to do it all, if obvious and easy methods/technology to handle some of your logic appear to you.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. There are some cases when I look for sub-graphs not in the entire graph, but from specific nodes(limiting the above query): g.V().hasLabel('PC', 'id1', 'id2')..., trying to find closest sub-networks to provided PC ids. Is there a way to get my first 2 questions working in gremlin?

Comment: If you start from a small enough set of vertices then you might be able to just use OLTP-based Gremlin to solve your problem, but whether or not that works well depends on the structure of your graph and the number of paths that Gremlin has to traverse to get your answer. Assuming that the "connected components" traversal worked for you in that case as OLTP you could then take the output of that and just write it to another graph with Gremlin. In the most coarse approach you could just use `sideEffect()` step with a lambda at the end of that traversal to do whatever you like with those groups.